# Jquery is not showing all enhanced dynamically appended radio buttons

Tags: jquery, css, arrays, ajax, jquery-mobile

I receive an array from ajax call and build a series of radio boxes using the array's elements. It works well until I try to refresh them to apply jqm markup. I only see two out of 4 expected, or one out of 3 expected. I have created a fiddle to illustrate the problem but the fiddle is not applying the markup at all, just shows correct number of boxes. The fiddle is: https://jsfiddle.net/wlukasz/9hno6pyh/7/. Here's my html:

```
<table class="std-table">
   <tr>
     <td><div id="areas"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and javascript:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#property-details-page', function(){   

all_areas = new Array();
var Q001Data = "sql=Q001&dbcall=sql_get_results_array&memid="+<?php echo $member_id?>+"&propid="+<?php echo $property_id?>;
$.ajax({ // ### AJAX to get ALL AREAS on page load ###
    url:"pl_process_ajax_call_property_features.php",
    type:"POST",
    data : Q001Data,
    success:function(msg){
        $("#areas").html('<fieldset id="all-areas-radio" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true"></fieldset>');
        all_areas = JSON.parse(msg);
        var textToInsert = '';
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < all_areas.length; i++) {
            var area = JSON.stringify(all_areas[i][0]);
            alert(area+i);
            textToInsert  += '<input type="radio" class="all-areas" name="property-area" id="' + area + '" value="' + area + '"><label for="' + area + '">' + area + '</label>';    
            alert(textToInsert);
        }
        $("#all-areas-radio").append(textToInsert);    
        $("[type=radio]").checkboxradio();
        $("[data-role=controlgroup]").controlgroup().controlgroup("refresh");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error Q001!");
    },
}); // ### AJAX to get ALL AREAS on page load ###
}); // ### document.on
```

I also use this css to change button label colour on "check":

```
<style>
#all-areas-radio div .ui-radio .ui-radio-on {
    background: orange !important;
}
</style>
```

All expected radio boxes show on screen until I try to apply jqm markup with this:

```
$("[type=radio]").checkboxradio();
$("[data-role=controlgroup]").controlgroup().controlgroup("refresh");
```

This is causing the markup applied correctly to 2 boxes out 4 expected and only the two enhanced are visible. If I expect 3 boxes I only receive one enhanced with two others invisible.
I run jquery 1.11 and jqm 1.45. Please help.

Comment: Update, just in. The array values come out of ajax call each enclosed in double quotes. When I tried to run it without ajax, just manually constructed array, the values came out without quotes and all works sweet. So why the double quotes affect my code?

Comment: so your question is now, how to remove the double quotes? BTW, your fiddle is not working.

Comment: That's my 1st fiddle ;-) , it was showing me the appended radio boxes... anyway, I have now removed the double quotes and the script works as intended. I will now mark my question as answered. I did not need these quotes. Although, the question remains what to do if you do want the quotes?

Comment: it would be nice if you adjust your question to reflect the real issue, in this way it may help other people, as this isn't an issue related to JQM. Please, inspect your markup without JQM and see what's happen with the double quotes in values and id's.

Comment: I don't know how to adjust the original question...but you are right, quotes don't have a place in ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a jQuery Mobile issue. The workflow here is conceptually wrong.

- You can't have quoted id's nor values. You should build your markup 
  in a different way. Ideally, you should keep separated names and values in your data, for example:

  `[{"id": "br", "name": "Bathroom"}, {"id": "be", "name": "Bedroom"},
    {"id": "ki", "name": "Kitchen"}, {"id": "lo", "name": "Lounge"}]`
- You should have control of what you get from your back-end.
  You may use some php functions to encode the data you need. What if your data is including, for example, a double quote due to a mistake? You would see the correct description in your `label`, but `id` and `value` would be completely wrong.

Here is an example how to adjust your controlgroup, but it is just a workaround. You should rethink the way to exchange data from (and probably back to) your server.

```js
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#property-details-page", function() {
    loadAreas(["\"description \n quoted\" & a new line", "Bathroom", "Bedroom", "Kitchen", "Lounge"]);
});


function loadAreas(areas) {
    var container = $("#property-details-content");
    container.empty();
    var controlGroup = $('<fieldset id="areas" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true"></fieldset>');
    container.append(controlGroup);
    for (var i = 0, l=areas.length; i < l; i++) {
        var area = areas[i];
        var clean = area.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "_");
        var control = $('<input type="radio" class="all-areas" name="property-area" id="' + clean + '" value="' + clean + '"><label for="' + clean + '">' + area + '</label>');
        controlGroup.append(control);
    }
    container.enhanceWithin();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="property-details-page" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>Property details</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="property-details-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this example. It is much neater way of doing it. I am only an amateur building a property management tool for a friend. I find it disconcerting with javascript that you can do the same thing in so many ways. I cleanse user input before inserting into the database, allowing only characters, numbers and spaces. I suspect that the quotes are added by `json` encoding and decoding in ajax call. I will try to resolve this so that no action is required on client side.

Comment: @Voytek: yes, first and last double quotes are from JSON.stringify, If my answer helped you, please consider to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the double quotes by:

```
area = area.replace(/['"']/g,'');
```

and the script works fine. The question remains however, what to do if you do need quotes as a part of the string?